# How to send same files with different names in JMeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have some problem. I am preparing load test of application, which is receiving binary data from physical device. I need to send a lot of files (ca 500k). But in reality, its ca 50 files with other names. When I am using standard HTTP Request sampler, I can specify path to file. And in this case I should have a lot of files (50GB?). Is there any possibility to specify path to some file, and in filename in posted data add some numbers? I would like to avoid solution with Read/WriteAllBytes in preprocessor, it will be big test performance killer.

Answer (score 0):

If you run on Linux, one possible solution is to create many link (ln) to few files.
If you are on Windows, you have to do physical copies.
Then I would create a list of file names, put in a CSV file, and read the file name to send from there.
Remember to set the "Recycle on EOF=true" in the CSV controller.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to work on Windows. And I was trying to avoid doing physical copies. But if there is no other solution... And yes - I am using CSV file to keep filenames.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the request yourself and use variables or functions to do just about anything. Can you represent your request using CURL and put the syntax here? Or copy and paste the HTTP request here?